# Codename One - Get IMEI from iOS device

Tags: ios, codenameone, imei

I need to know the IMEI number of iOS devices, running my Codename One app.

Reading [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040610/how-to-get-current-system-dns-resolvers-ip-addresses-in-codename-one), it seems it's not possible. Is it still impossible to get the IMEI number? And about the serial number? Any workaround to suggest?

Comment: You can get the UDID, but can not get the IMEI. Apple does not allow this. It is against security policy of Apple

Comment: Has nothing to do with the hybrid tooling you are using. Its not possible to get it on iOS devices due to security issues.

Comment: try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600969/device-fingerprinting-android-and-ios/50601453#50601453

Comment: @PPL you can’t get the UDID either.

Comment: As others have said even the UDID number returned is a pseudo number and will return a different value with every app install. That's an Apple restrictions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, iOS does not let you get at persistent unique identifiers (the IMEI, the UDID, the Wi-Fi MAC address, and so on) ([source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31122)).

In the [developer guide of Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/signing.html), it's written:

> Don’t use an app to get the UDID! Most return the wrong value, the
>   official way to get the UDID is thru itunes.

If you need to identify uniquely the device, the best that you can do is to use the Codename One method `Log.getUniqueDeviceId()`.

According to [its Javadoc](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Log.html#getUniqueDeviceId--):

> Returns a server generated unique device id that is cached locally and
>   is only valid per application. Notice that this device id is specific
>   to your application and to a specific install, **it is guaranteed to be
>   completely unique** or -1 if unavailable (which can be due to a network
>   error). Warning: this method might block while accessing the server!

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I imagine is the same for serial number, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, Apple has removed access to the serial number (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926251/get-serial-number-of-device-on-ios-8)